# When using `automatic_tax`, each shipping option needs to have a defined `tax_behavior` set. error while automatic tax in stripe

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

While calculating tax according to the shipping region I am getting this error

[Error while hitting the checkout API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKPP5.jpg)

I have used the following code the checkout

[Code for the checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB70N.jpg)

Comment: Seems like the hint is right in the error message. Have you defined a `tax_behavior` for each shipping option? What does the Stripe documentation say?

Comment: How to define tax behaviour for shipping option ... i couldn’t find the documentation regarding that ... if u have any idea ... please assist me

Comment: I Googled "stripe tax behavior" and it was the first hit: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/taxes/collect-taxes — Read through that and see if it helps.

Comment: Got the answer ... add  tax_behavior:'inclusive', in the shipping options. and the error is resolved ... (inclusive/exclusive/unspecified) according to the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Shipping Options with Checkout and automatic tax, then you need to set `shipping_options.shipping_rate_data.tax_behavior` when you create the Session. You can see it in the API reference here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_options-shipping_rate_data-tax_behavior